# AppleScript grab value from safari with repeat / add in list

Tags: applescript, javascript

I need to grab data from a safari,
There is a random number of :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sortable DataSummary')[1]
```

this work fine :

```
tell application "Safari"
    set mzRawData to do JavaScript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('sortable DataSummary');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;" in current tab of window 1
end tell
```

the return is a bit annoying with some space and line e.g :

```
>  ", "
>                                 
>                                     WeChat Pay
>                                 
>                             ", "
```

My question :

How can I do the same using an AppleScript repeat statement ?
This is not working but here is my draft at the moment

```
set mzRawData to ""

repeat with i from 1 to count of items of mzRawData

    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('sortable DataSummary')[" & i & "].innerHTML;" in current tab of window 1

    end tell

end repeat
```

and

```
set mzRawData to ""
set myNewList to {}
repeat until mzRawData contains "current application"
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('sortable DataSummary')[" & i & "].innerHTML;" in current tab of window 1
        set itemOnMyList to item each of mzRawData
        if itemOnMyList is in mzRawData and itemOnMyList is not in myNewList then set end of myNewList to itemOnMyList  
    end tell
end repeat
```